# Why are the results different when using <=> operator in PHP 7 and PHP 8?

Tags: php

Why are the results different when using <=> operator in PHP 7 and PHP 8?

In PHP 7:

```
echo 76 <=> '76 trombones';  // displays 0
```

In PHP 8:

```
echo 76 <=> '76 trombones';  // displays -1
```

Comment: In PHP 8 the number is cast to a string to compare. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php#migration80.incompatible.core.string-number-comparision

Comment: The code you've posted is not code that you should be writing on purpose anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP 8 changed the way non-strict comparison between numbers and non-numeric strings work.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration80.incompatible.php#migration80.incompatible.core.string-number-comparision)

`<=>` is a non-strict comparison.

The values in your example, `76` and `'76 trombones'` evaluated as equal in PHP 7 because the string was cast to a number for the comparison, and `(int) '76 trombones'` is `76`.

Now in PHP 8, the number is cast to string for the comparison instead.